# Python pySpark : reduceByKey Running total calculation

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a list of tuples after a join that look exactly like this

```
                        [(u'something1', u'500'),
                         (u'something1', u'200'),
                         (u'something1', u'300'),
                         (u'something2', u'200'),
                         (u'something2', u'600'),
                         (u'something2', u'400')]
```

The U at the start of the tuple I believe represents a Unicode character

I have written a function in pySpark to do the calculation to get a result something like this. The function basically needs to sum up the total of the counts that occur for each of the key

```
              (something1, 1000),
               (something2, 1200)
```

Here is my function

```
                 def calc_counts(a, b)
                     return a+b
```

Then I do a

```
              joined_data.reduceByKey(calc_counts).collect()
```

This gives me a result which is a number spanning 10 lines like 
                   (u'something1, 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,)

How can I reedit that function calc_counts.

**Note:** I may not be able to import any libraries as this is being performed at the console and not as a stored python file.

Comment: is the second element of your tuple a string?

Comment: what is the output of `joined_data.take(10)` ?

Comment: The data set is the result of a join. It is a tuple. appears exactly as in the question. I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using spark, there is very simple way of doing what you want to achieve using existing apis. Writing your own function for already working apis doesnt make sense.

I assume, you data after join is as follows -

```
data =    [(u'something1', u'500'),
            (u'something1', u'200'),
            (u'something1', u'300'),
            (u'something2', u'200'),
            (u'something2', u'600'),
            (u'something2', u'400')]

rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
```

to find sum of the total of the counts that occur for each of the key, all you need to do is -

```
rdd \
.mapValues(lambda x : int(x)) \
.reduceByKey(lambda x,y : x+y) \
.collect()
```

here, `mapValues` will convert values which are currently in stringformat `u'500'` to integer `500` and anonymous function `lambda x,y : x+y` will sum all the values for all keys.

Comment: This piece of code                                                                                      
                                   "rdd = sc.parallelize(data)"  is giving me this error              "PipelinedRDD object is not iterable". I think the current values are tuples and not string.

Comment: I used `rdd = sc.parallelize(data)` just to create rdd, if you already have rdd which is result of some join operation, you dont need to do that step.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution, you can also use `groupby` to group by the first key and sum each group together

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    (u'something1', u'500'),
    (u'something1', u'200'),
    (u'something1', u'300'),
    (u'something2', u'200'),
    (u'something2', u'600'),
    (u'something2', u'400')])

out = rdd.groupBy(lambda x: x[0]).map(lambda x: Row(**{'key': x[0], 'sum': sum([int(e[1]) for e in x[1]])})).collect()
```

**out** is a list of `Row`

```
[Row(key='something2', sum=1200), Row(key='something1', sum=1000)]
```

Comment: @Raghu, I updated the solution. You have to import `Row` from `pyspark.sql` first.

Comment: No problem @Raghu! Hope it helps as an alternative solution later on :)